# How to hide some column to be selected in the supabase frontend query?

Tags: security, supabase

Let's say you have a table `table_a` which has some columns along with `internal_usage_column`.

In frontend, you can query like `supabase.from('table_a').select('*');` to fetch data. It would select all the rows. Or you could do selecting some of the columns.

In anyway, I don't want to allow the frontend to select my `internal_usage_column`.

Is `supabase` has such functionality? If yes, how to do that? Or any other alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

Its a late response, but for those who are seeking the answer, you can create a view in the supabase dashboard by selecting only the columns that you want to be exposed.

Eg: you have a table named `users` where you have normal and private columns and want only `id`, `name` and `email` to be exposed, then create a view that only selects these columns.
From the left sidebar in supabase dashboard, navigate to: SQL Editor --> New Query and use the following sql:

```
create view public.users_view as select id,name,email from users;
```

Now instead of querying from the table `users` directly, we will query from the view `users_view` that we just created:

```
supabase.from('users_view').select('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for this would be to create two tables one for public data and another for private data.

A more complicated solution would be to grant access rights to certain columns that you would like to show only to specific users.
https://github.com/supabase/supabase/pull/13745#issuecomment-1807283973

Answer (score -1):

Im' not super familiar with supabase, but in SQL, the solution is not to select '*', but select the columns you want.

Comment: Seems you didn't understand the problem. Anyway, appreciate you tried.